# How do you handle NullReferences in EF when creating a new entity in runtime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following example schema:

```
public class CounterReading
{
    public int CounterReadingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Counter Counter { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Reading { get; set; }

    public CounterReading()
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class Counter
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Meter")]
    public int CounterId { get; set; }

    public virtual Meter Meter { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableCollection<CounterReading> Readings { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public CounterReading CurrentReading
    {
        get
        {
            if(Readings.Count > 0)
            {
                return Readings.MaxBy(m => m.Reading);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Meter
{
    public int MeterId { get; set; }
    public string EANNumber { get; set; }
    public string MeterNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Premise Premise { get; set; }
}

public class WaterMeter : Meter
{
    public virtual Counter Counter { get; set; }

    public WaterMeter()
    {
        Counter = new Counter();
        Counter.Readings = new ObservableCollection<CounterReading>();
    }
}
```

And what doesn't work is that my `WaterMeter` does not have any `CounterReadings` when I load it from database. This is because I set my `Counter` in my constructor, to avoid `NullReferencesExceptions` when I create a new `WaterMeter` in runtime.

If I remove my `WaterMeter`constructor, EF loads my readings just fine. But that means I have loads of NullReferences when using my application without reloading my data each and every time.

What's the best way to solve this?

Edit:
NRE:
[image]

Comment: What NRE do you get? As far as I am aware foreign key collections are never null, just empty.

Comment: @James My `Readings` property is null. See the added image.

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly, there is a disjoint in the code you have in your question and the actual code you are executing (as per the image you added) which is why I couldn't see a problem.

However, from the image you posted it's clear that the problem is the fact that you have `Readings` as a `private` field - EF CodeFirst requires navigation properties to be marked as `public virtual` in order for them to be initialised.

Comment: I've only added the private field to try out @EvgenyKorolyuk's answer, which works. But if it's possible to do this without backing fields, I'd prefer that.

Comment: @BenjaminDiele you absolutely don't need backing fields, Readings should be initialised by EF when you attempt to access it. If Readings *is* null then it would suggest that the problem lies in your database i.e. The relationship is not configured correctly.

Comment: How can I check if my relationships are configured correctly?

Comment: Can I export it somehow or find it without typing it out?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which DB you are actually using so I can't really lend an opinion on how you can do that. However, surely it wouldn't take long to write out a schema for what the relationship for those 2 tables looks like?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid null reference exception with collection, you should introduce local readonly collection field and initialize it empty collection.

```
    public class Counter
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<CounterReading> readings = new ObservableCollection<CounterReading>();

    public virtual ObservableCollection<CounterReading> Readings
    {
        get { return readings; }
        set { readings = value; }
    }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Meter")]
    public int CounterId { get; set; }

    public virtual Meter Meter { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public CounterReading CurrentReading
    {
        get
        {
           return Readings.MaxBy(m => m.Reading);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hou also marked the collection property virtual. Could you explains why? :-)

Comment: Entity framework create proxy objects dynamically. So it need virtual fields

Answer (score 0):

I've got one addition to Evgeny's answer. Instead of always creating a new instance of the collection , you can make it conditionally so it only creates a new instance when this property is actually called:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<CounterReading> readings;
public virtual ObservableCollection<CounterReading> Readings
{
    get 
    { 
       if(_readings == null) 
       {
         _readings = new ObservableCollection<CounterReading>();
       }
       return readings; 
    }
    set { readings = value; }
}
```

If you don't need to add logic to the getter and setter, why don't you consider using this:

```
public virtual ObservableCollection<CounterReading> Readings {get;set;}
```